# Как работать с нескомпилированным Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, javascript

При использовании bootstrap для разработки сайтов, понял, что готовая версия не дает и половины преймуществ версии с Less переменными. Скачал исходники с github, но что то совсем не могу понять что писать в мой index.htm, а именно какие файлы подключать кроме less.js . Подскажите пожалуйста как организовать работу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LESS на клиентской стороне подключается так:

```
<!-- наши стили -->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
<!-- сам less.js -->
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо, это я понимаю, мне интересно есть ли в bootstrape файл который подключает все bootstrap файлы из папки less или это самому собирать?
UPD: всё разобрался, если кармы хватит сам отвечу щас)

Comment: bootstrap.less содержит все inludes. Не знаю, как это будет работать с less.js

Comment: да, действительно пока не подключаются стили почему то

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/Downloads/bootstrap-master/bootstrap-master/less/bootstrap.less. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. 
при подключении less.js

Comment: Логично. Читайте по поводу кроссдоменных запросов.

Comment: Нужно запускать на сервере(можно локальном)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете сырой бутстрап, то вам нужно заинклудить центральный файл бутстрапа в ваш файл.
 Скомпилировать все это дело при помощи gulp или grunt, или чего-нибуть еще и подключить то что получилось в виде css в ваш файл где необходимо вывести эти стили.

Для того чтобы хаинклудить вам нужно написать
@import(../путь/до/файла/бутстрап.less);